# Parsing an excel file without library

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I am trying to parse an Excel spreadsheet which contains information in each row. I need to extract specific information from each row, and then work with that information.

Namely, say each row is of the format a, b, c, d, e, and then the variable 'c' is repeated in each row of the spreadsheet, I need to extract 'c' from each row and then be able to count the number of 'c's.

I apologise for not posting the code - I am not able to, as this would plagiarise me.

Any help or ideas on how I could go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to help you without any form of example.
I think you could use the [COUNT.IF formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"conditions that are true if format is type C")
```

Look at some examples you can find in the documentation page...or post some example.
To extract some values you could use a combination of MID, MIDB, SEARCH, ... functions.